# What is the conventional way to distinguish the Taylor's Polynomial of one function from another's?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let's say I have two functions, f(x) and g(x) and I want to make second degree Taylor's polynomials out of both. I can't use the same name ($T_{2}(x;x_{0})$
) for both of them. How can I

Do I put the function inside parentheses?

$T_{2}(x;x_{0};f(x))$

$T_{2}(x;x_{0};g(x))$

Or will the function go into the subindex?

$T_{2;f}(x;x_{0})$

$T_{2;g}(x;x_{0})$

Or will I just use different letters for the functions themselves?

$T_{2;f}(x;x_{0})$

$G_{2;g}(x;x_{0})$

I know this is more of a style issue. But I'm curious what is the conventional way!

Comment: I have never seen specific notation for the $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial of a function $f$ centered at $a$.  If you *need* such notation for some purpose, why not just invent your own?  As long as you are clear about your definition, and use it consistently, you should be understood.

Comment: I've seen $T_nf(x;x_0)$ for the $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ centered at $x_0$. But I doubt there being some universal convention.

Comment: subscript vs brackets are purely convention, but writing $f(x)$ for the function is strictly speaking wrong. The single letter $f$ denotes the function, while $f(x)$ denotes the value of the function $f$ at the point $x$. I've seen many variants of $T_{n,x_0,f}$ or $P_{n,x_0,f}$ or $P_n(f,x_0)(\cdot)$ (or your second option) etc but don't write $f(x)$.